# Android system partition getting mount as read-only automatically

Tags: android, root, mount, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am using Android 5.1.1 and I need to work on /system. I already have root access and I know how to mount partitions to do what I want, but in this version, it doesn't work as it should.
I am rooting the device using Kingo Root and then I'm converting it to SuperSU. The mount command I am using is `mount -o,remount rw /system`.

When I am using Kingo Root, the system partition gets, in fact, rewritable. When I use SuperSU the partition gets rewritable for a few seconds (literally few) and then goes back to read-only.

This is the result of the mount command after remounting the partition.

```
root@android:/ mount | grep system 
/dev/block/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.1/by-name/system /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

This makes me think that the Kingo Root binary/daemon does something that SuperSU one doesn't, but I cannot figure out what.

Additionally, what can be remounting the partition as read-only?

Has anyone else been through this? If so, any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after hitting the wall for some hours, I've finally found out the problem. 
First I thought it had something to do with the `mount` command since the behaviours were different when using Kingo Root and SuperSu, but then I checked it out and they were the same. After digging the transition to SuperSU I noticed that the binaries were having some differences and I've re-made the transition and it wall worked like a charm. It seems that I had some leftovers of the initial root messing up with the second one.